# Copy over background color from a cell to another table cell

Tags: jquery, css

I got this working but the solution feels kind of *dirty* so if someone can take a look at it and give hints on how to optimize the approach that would be great.

I have a particular starting table with background colors set. Underneath it are similar tables without background colors, in reality these are created dynamically for each record in an array that I retrieve via ajax. The purpose of the script is that the background colors for every *column* in the resulting grid are copied over:

```
for (var i = 2; i < 34; i++) {
    var c = $('table tr td:nth('+ i + ')').css('background-color');        
    $('table tr td:nth-child('+i+')').css('background-color',c);
}
```

I now first find the background color from the first table then in the loop copy over this found color.

Small update: it needs to work in at least IE 8.

An example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/KvdM/9RRfU/.

Comment: You can do one thing here. Why don't you have a class that holds the backgroundColor, and then when you add the table dynamically include the class with it for td.. But that might become too tedious.. But also I don't think the script is looking bad !!

Comment: The _header_ table can change dynamically so it's not each time the same day column that gets the background color.
It's indeed not a bad script as it work (famous last words) but it feels like it could be optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code grabs the first row of table cells and iterates over them. It caches the jQuery wrapped `this` implicit parameter and gets it's column location in the table as well as it's `background-color`. Next it updates the rest of the table cells at that location with the same `background-color`.

```
$(function() {
    $( "tr:first td" ).each(function() {
        var $this = $( this ),
            index = $this.index(),
            color = $this.css( "background-color" );

        $( "td:nth-child(" + index + ")" ).css( "background-color", color )
    });
});
```

​
Here is a jsFiddle with the above snippet... http://jsfiddle.net/fpVuW/

You might consider adding a special class to the tables and updating the jQuery so it only manipulates those tables, otherwise if there are any other tables on your page they will get changed too.

Another solution would be to create a function or plugin that copies one table to another specific table and then call the function/plugin for each table. That way you'd have more control over which tables get changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider just using CSS3 col and nth-child. See example with red cols:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdejuan/9RRfU/5/

Additional info on [Col elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/col.html)

Comment: That solution doesn't work for me apparently (Chrome version whatever latest). Also it needs to work in IE 8 and perhaps also in IE 7 in the future.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE8. It does work in Chrome, perhaps I pasted the wrong link

Comment: Also not in IE 10 when I open the fiddle.

I noticed the updated fiddle but it only adds the colors to the first table instead of copying them over to the other tables.